# How can I sign in a user using SSO with the identity platform REST API

Tags: dart, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I'm want to use the identity platform REST API to sign in my users. But looking at the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-send-email-verification) I can't seem to find how to sign in a user using SSO or Phone number. How can I do this? Or where can I find the full documentation that does include SSO and Phone number.

We want to opt out of using the Firebase auth sdk since it does not support all the platforms we need. And also we want the package that has the auth to be a dependency of both dart and flutter projects, so having the firebase sdk as a dependency will cause problems there.

Comment: Why the REST API? Are you implementing this in a client, or on the server? https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication

Comment: On the client. The firebase auth package (flutter) doesn't support all the platforms yet that we want to use. And we also have pure dart applications that need to use it, so that would not work. Also we don't use any firebase services so we want to avoid being dependend on the sdk.

Comment: Okta's Auth0 solution is an option too? https://auth0.com/ You can certainly roll your own solution but you've got to weight the time/cost in terms of development hours. Probably best to use a pre-rolled solution like Firebase Auth, then if your app takes off in term of usage you'll have a budget to afford a custom solution.

Comment: So Identity platform has no endpoints for SSO or Phone number sign in? Or at least SSO? Anything else then Identity platform won't be an option for us

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport

Comment: We are not working with javascript. We are working with flutter + dart. Would you happen to know if there is a way to explore the full rest api for identity platform? I have a feeling endpoints are missing from the docs.

Comment: You can explore the Google Identity REST API at Google API Explorer. https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/  `To call this service, we recommend that you use the Google-provided
 client libraries. If your application needs to use your own libraries
 to call this service, use the following information when you make the
 API requests.` ...